# Incompatible types for mimemessage

Tags: java

we have a project that is sending an email to our users.

The line that's causing a problem is:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

however it's displaying the following errors when I hover over it:

```
incompatible types.
required: javax.jms.message
found: javax.mail.internet.mimeMessage
```

I have javaee-api-7.0.jar as a dependency on the project. I'm not quite sure why it's having a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported the wrong message class or you're referencing two classes with the same name (different package) in the same class, fully qualify it like so:

```
java.mail.Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```